# How to populate missing values for string variable in a column based on fixed criteria

Tags: stata

[To populate missing data with a fixed range of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FUbr.jpg)

I would like to check how to populate column `aktype` with a range of values (the range of values for the same pidlink are always fixed at 11 types of values listed below) for those cells with missing values. I have about 17,000+ observations that are missing.

The range of values are as follows:
A
B
C
D
E
G
H
I
J
K
L

I have tried the following command but it does not work:-

```
foreach x of varlist aktype=1/11 {
 replace aktype = "A" in 1 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "B" in 2 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "C" in 3 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "D" in 4 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "E" in 5 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "G" in 6 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "H" in 7 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "I" in 8 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "J" in 9 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "K" in 10 if aktype=="" 
 replace aktype = "L" in 11 if aktype=="" 
    }
```

Would appreciate it if you could advise on the right command to use. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a variable `AK` that has letters A-K in positions 1-11 (and 12-22, and 23-33, and so on). The replace missing values with the value of this variable `AK`.

```
* generate data
clear
set obs 20
generate aktype = ""
replace aktype = "foo" in 1/1
replace aktype = "bar" in 10/12

* generate variable with letters A-K
generate AK = char(65 + mod(_n - 1, 11))

* fill missing values
replace aktype = AK if missing(aktype)
list
```

This yields the following.

```
. list

     +-------------+
     | aktype   AK |
     |-------------|
  1. |    foo    A |
  2. |      B    B |
  3. |      C    C |
  4. |      D    D |
  5. |      E    E |
     |-------------|
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

This first addresses the comment "it does not work".

Generally, in this kind of forum you should always be specific and say exactly what happens, namely where the code breaks down and what the result is (e.g. what error message you get). If necessary, add why that is not what is wanted.

Specifically, in this case Stata would get no further than

```
foreach x of varlist aktype=1/11
```

which is illegal (as well as unclear to Stata programmers).

You can loop over a *varlist*. In this case looping over a single variable `aktype` is legal. (It is usually pointless, but that's style, not syntax.) So this is legal:

```
foreach x of varlist aktype
```

By the way, you define `x` as the loop argument, but never refer to it inside the loop. That isn't illegal, but it is unusual.

You can also loop over a *numlist*, e.g.

```
foreach x of numlist 1/11
```

although

```
forval x = 1/11
```

is a more direct way of doing that. All this follows from the syntax diagrams for the commands concerned, where whatever is not explicitly allowed is forbidden.

On occasions when you need to loop over a *varlist* and a *numlist* you will need to use different syntax, but what is best depends on the precise problem.

Now second to the question: I can't see any kind of rule in the question for which values get assigned `A` through `L`, so can't advise positively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and suggestions. I am not a programmer and also new to Stata (sorry I did not make that clear as well). I will be more specific the next time I pose a question.